# Picup App VS. cliqcliq Quickpic

Tags: ipad, file-upload, mobile, webforms, ios

Weekend research has shown me that, in mobile Safari, my best chances for the upload of an image file from the iOS photo library are through cliqcliq's Quickpic app or PicUp for iPhone.

Are there any other choices that are more seamless or better than both of these apps?

*This project i'm developing will use iPads for this task.